# UWP InkCanvas differences between PC and Surface HUB

Tags: uwp, surface-hub

Is there any difference in a UWP InkCanvas between a PC and a Surface Hub?

I have deployed the same app package on both a PC and a Surface Hub. Everything works as expected on the PC. On the hub, the strokes have gaps when you draw a little faster.

Here's a sample picture of a rectangle drawn fast on the hub:

[image]

My InkCanvas is used inside a ScrollViewer for the Zoom and Pan functionality, like this:

```
    <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="2" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged" >

        <InkCanvas x:Name="InkCanvas"  MinWidth="100000" MinHeight="100000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="InkCanvas_Loaded" />

    </ScrollViewer>
```

This is exactly the same app with exactly the same code. The app is using the Creators Update SDK. The Hub also has the Creators Update installed.

I should also point out that I don't have a testing surface hub yet, this has been reported by my client, there's no easy way for me to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the battery from the pen used to draw on the hub.